# Kahn's algorithm vs DFS for course schedule leetcode

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Course Schedule leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/

This problem involves detecting a cycle, and if there is one then you cannot complete all course.

I've heard that DFS is most recommended for detecting a cycle, yet Kahn's Algorithm is recommended for the course schedule problem, which is a BFS solution.

So.. which is it? Is DFS better for detecting cycles or is BFS?

Comment: The biggest difference is that Khan's must always continue to the end, DFS can chance up on the cycle much earlier if there is one. The good question is who is faster when there is no cycle and the is a quality of implementation question.

Comment: Khan's algorithm has nothing to do with BFS

Answer (score 6):

Both have a time complexity of O(V+E) and both have a space complexity of O(V+E). So in those terms there is no winner.

One uses a queue, the other a stack. One uses a degree per node, the other a visited mark per node.

One difference is that DFS can use an implicit stack using recursion, which may make the code a bit more compact. But then again, you're then limited by the available call stack space, so using recursion may not be a viable solution for large inputs, and using an explicit stack may in the end be the option to take for a DFS-based solution.

So all in all, they come out equal. Choose either.

Answer (score 2):

In real work, it's always a bad idea to use O(N) stack space, so practical DFS-based solutions would use an explicit stack.

The explicit stack implementation is a little complicated, because the stack isn't just a stack of nodes -- you also need to store the current position in the child list for each open node -- and the traversal logic gets a little complicated.

The DFS solution is not awful, but if you want to write a good solid solution, then Khan's algorithm will end up simpler and faster in the worst case.  It will also use less memory, because the list of pending nodes is just a list of nodes.  (It doesn't matter if you use that list like a stack or queue.  In most cases using it like a stack is faster/easier)

So if you're going to explicitly check a directed graph to see if it has cycles, usually Kahn's algorithm is best.  The DFS technique is useful if you're already doing a DFS for some other reason and you want to detect cycles along the way.