# Detecting Cycle in directed Graph using stack and DFS Traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to detect the cycle in a directed graph. Initially, I have assumed all nodes to be unvisited and have their value as `-1` in `vector<int>flag.` Now we start from a source node and push into `stack<int>s` and make `flag[source]=0` as it is present in stack. Now I will do the DFS traversal and push the nodes `if(flag[node]==-1)`& make `flag[node]=0` in stack starting with that particular source that I pushed in first. if all the DFS directed links are visited I will pop the top element of the stack and mark it `flag[s.top()]=1`;
while pushing if we encounter a node with `flag[nodes]==0`, **the cycle is detected** and i do an increment in `int final` variable;`

my code works correctly but there is a little issue. for e.g for input with `number of vertices and edges =3`.

```
input edges:{1,3},{2,3},{3,2}
```

input format;

```
3 3
1 3
2 3
3 2

expected out: "Graph is cyclic"
```

if i take the only source as 2 then i get the correct answer, but if we have to check it considering each vertex as source so i use a for loop but now i get the wrong output **Graph is not cyclic**. will kindly request why my approach go wrong.

my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int mx=1e5+5;
vector<bool>vist(mx);
vector<vector<int>>Graph(mx);
void dfs(int node,vector<int>&dfs_vec){
    vist[node]=true;
    dfs_vec.push_back(node);
    for(int neigh: Graph[node]){
        if(!vist[neigh]){
            dfs(neigh,dfs_vec);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int num_vertex;int num_edge;
    cin>>num_vertex>>num_edge;
    int u,v;
    for(int i=0;i<num_edge;i++){
        cin>>u>>v;
        Graph[u].push_back(v);
    }
    int final=0;
    for(int source=1;source<=num_vertex;source++){
    vector<int>flag(num_vertex+1,-1);
    stack<int>s;
    s.push(source);
    flag[source]=0;
    while(!s.empty()){
        int x=s.top();
        vector<int>temp;
        dfs(Graph[x][0],temp);
        for(auto y:temp){
            if(flag[y]==-1){
                s.push(y);
                flag[y]=0;
            }
            else if(flag[y]==0){
                final++;
            }
        }
        flag[s.top()]=1;
        s.pop();

    }
    flag.clear();
    while(!s.empty()){
        s.pop();
    }
    }
    if(final>0){
        std::cout<<" Graph is cyclic";
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<" Graph is not cyclic";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a very small failing example, so start debugging (even possible with pen and paper).

Comment: What algorithm is this supposed to be?

Comment: @surt sir Using either DFS, or  BFS, or Topological sorting it is done. I'm trying to use DFS. will be thankful if you may help to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307377/kahns-algorithm-vs-dfs-for-course-schedule-leetcode/68310296#68310296

Comment: In a DAG, just because you find two paths to a node, it doesn't mean there's a cycle.  In the DFS test, you need to find an edge to an *unfinished* node, not just a visited one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869647/why-dfs-and-not-bfs-for-finding-cycle-in-graphs/58211392#58211392

Comment: @Matt Timmermans thank you for letting me know,but i am still unsure why my code fails